# hitest on a TTStyledText returns a empty frame even when user clicks on a valid link

Tags: three20, iphone

I have styled text with multiple URLs. While all the URLs links get highlighted, only some pass the hittest when the user taps on them. As a result of this not all links are handled properly in three20 framework. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style class name needs to end with : and the stylesheet selector with get the state when style is retrieved.

The easiest way would be to not to specify the class name at all. The label works well in this scenario. the problem occurs only when one specifies a custom class for the the label.